# Testing Python code that relies on hardware

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, hardware

So I have some code which uses gphoto2 to capture some images and stuff, I figured the best way to test this would be to wrap the gphoto2 code in something like an if TESTING: then return fake data, else do the gphoto2 stuff.

Does anyone know how I would achieve this, I've tried googling some things but I've not had any luck with specifically detecting if unit tests are being run or not.

I'd assume it would be something like if unittest: but maybe there is a better way to do this altogether?

EDIT:
So based on the comments and answers so far, I tried out the unittest.mock package, it didn't work as I'd hoped, let me explain.

If I have method A which calls the capture image method (method B), then saves the image and a few other bits. I've managed to mock method B so that it returns either the image or None, which works fine when I call method B specifically, but when I try to call method A, it doesn't use the mock of method B, it uses the actual method B.

How do I make method A use the mock method B?

Comment: You shouldn't have `if TESTING:` in your code, then you aren't testing the code that's actually running; use *"mocking"* to create a version of `gphoto2` that returns your dummy data.

Comment: The `gphoto2` code will only be a small part of what you are doing. Test the other part.

Comment: @PeterWood my code uses Django and DRF to recieve an API request and then use gphoto2 to capture an image and then return the URL to the image. So really I'd only be testing that if gphoto2 has or hasn't returned an image then my API either returns a URL or a 400_BAD_REQUEST... So there isn't much to test. Thorough scenario testing has proven that it all works fine, but I'm expected to write unit tests for all code that we write.

Comment: @Cephlin You need an abstraction that can be mocked, for example an `image_source` which can return an image or `None`.

Comment: So do I write my mock in the actual capture image class or in my test class? The documentation is a little confusing...

Comment: You shouldn't have test code in your normal code. Michael Feathers talks about [test seams](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=3), places in your code where one thing can be unravelled and replaced with another for the purposes of testing.

Comment: So I tried using the mocks, it didn't work for me, I assume I'm doing it wrong, let me explain. I have method A and method B. I have full testing on method B complete before I posted this question (this method relies on the hardware). I then use method A to call method B. I tried to test method A by mocking the returns of method B, but the method B mocks I made only work when I call method B instead of calling method A. So the mocking is only working when I call method B directly, but I want to test method A using the method B mock which isn't calling the mock I've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a mocking library from within your test code. This way you'd mask the external APIs (hardware calls in your case) and return predictable values.
I would recommend **flexmock** https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flexmock it's super easy.

In the beginning of your test code, you'll write something like:
`flexmock(SomeObject).should_receive('some_method').and_return('some', 'values')`

Answer (score 2):

The [mock](https://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#introduction) package exists for this very reason.

It's a standalone, pip-installable package for Python 2; it has been incorporated into the standard library for Python versions >= 3.3 (as `unittest.mock`).